# Packed Record из делфи в Java

Tags: java, delphi, jna

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с проблемой вызова запакованной записи из DLL, написанной на делфи.
Есть функция в делфи, которая использует как аргумент запакованную запись:

```
type
  {информация о счёте}
  TAccountInfo = packed record
    Size      : Word;    // SizeOf( TAccountInfo )
    Account   : Integer; // номер счёта
    Card      : Int64;   // номер карты
    Holder    : Array[0..40] of Char; //ФИО
    Scheme    : Byte;    {тип счёта:  0 - ручное пополнение без ограничения оплат 1 - автоматическое пополнение без ограничения оплат
                          2 - автоматическое пополнение с лимитом оплат на один день
                          3 - автоматическое пополнение с лимитом оплат на неделю
                          4 - автоматическое пополнение с лимитом оплат на месяц
                          5 - ручное пополнение с лимитом оплат на один день
                          6 - ручное пополнение с лимитом оплат на неделю
                          7 - ручное пополнение с лимитом оплат на месяц
                          }
    Offered   : Integer; // дата выдачи (0 -> 30/12/1899)
    Expired   : Integer; // срок действия
    Birthday  : Integer; // день рождения
    Deleted   : BOOL;    // счёт удален?
    Locked    : BOOL;    // карта заблокирована?
    Seize     : BOOL;    // карту изъять?
    WhyLocked : Array[0..255] of Char; // причина блокировки - asciiz
    Discount  : Word;    // номер скидки
    Bonus     : Word;    // номер бонуса
    PayLimit  : Comp;    // лимит оплат для счетов c лимитом
    Female    : BOOL;    // пол
    Folder    : Word;    // идентификатор отдела
    Unpay     : Integer; // номер неплательщика
    Tel1      : Array[0..15] of Char; //телефон 1
    Tel2      : Array[0..15] of Char; //телефон 2
    Email     : Array[0..255] of Char;
    Address   : Array[0..255] of Char;
    DopInfo   : Array[0..255] of Char; //произвольная информация - asciiz
    Balance   : Comp;    // для карт с ручным пополнением - текущий остаток
  end;

{получить информацию о счёте}
Function GetAccountInfo( Account: Integer; var Info: TAccountInfo ): BOOL; stdcall;
```

При вызове функции `GetAccountInfo` указывается номер счёта, а затем требуется разметка для получения записи. Пробовал использовать структуру, но в ответ получаю сообщение из функции получения сообщения от DLL:

> Invalid record size

либо ошибку чтения памяти. При выводе из структуры записи имеют значение 0.

Ниже прикладываю свой код на Java:

```
//Вызов в интерфейсе CscLink
@Structure.FieldOrder({
"account", "adress", "balance", "birthday", "bonus", "card",
 "deleted", "discount", "dopInfo", "email", "expired", "folder",
 "holder", "locked", "offered", "payLimit", "scheme", "seize", "sex",
 "size", "tel1", "tel2", "unpay", "whyLocked"})
       public class TAccountInfo extends Structure{
           public char size;
        public int account;
        public long card;
        public char[] holder = new char[40];
        public byte scheme;
        public int offered;
        public int expired;
        public int birthday;
        public boolean deleted;
        public boolean locked;
        public boolean seize;
        public char[] whyLocked = new char[255];
        public char discount;
        public char bonus;
        public long payLimit;
        public boolean sex;
        public char folder;
        public int unpay;
        public char[] tel1 = new char[15];
        public char[] tel2 = new char[15];
        public char[] email = new char[255];
        public char[] adress = new char[255];
        public char[] dopInfo = new char[255];
        public long balance;
    }
    
//Вызов в Main
CscLink.TAccountInfo taco = new CscLink.TAccountInfo();
myLib.GetAccountInfo(getAccNumb.getValue(), taco);
System.out.println(taco.card);
```

Comment: Так а как вы её в Java то объявляете и вызываете? )

Comment: С помощью структуры, добавляю аннотацию `@Structure.FieldOrder({перечисление типов})`, а в теле структуры объявляю все 24 переменные с соответствующими типами. Пробовал использовать ByReference, но тоже не катит... Какой то инфы не смог найти в инете

Comment: var - передача указателя, так что ByReference, у вас, видимо. А объявление структуры на Java стоит показать.

Comment: Телепаты в релокации, пожалуйста полный релевантный код прикладывайте.

Comment: int size неправильно: word - это uint16. BOOL четырехбайтовый. Сомневаюсь, что Array[0..15] of Char похоже на ваш string

Comment: Даже если и так, то не совсем уверен что это должно вызываться именно таким образом... По идее если бы было не соответствие типов, была бы ошибка в самом JNA, но здесь ведь возвращается ответ от DLL-ки...

Comment: "Invalid record size" - вам как-бы намекает, что для кого-то в цепочке важен размер структуры, и он у вас .. инвалид.

Comment: На всякий случай - размер в Delphi (при Char=AnsiChar) 1166 байт.

Comment: Так, окей, по поводу без знакового 16 разрядного целого я разобрался, по аналогии подходит char. BOOL собственно как и boolean в java аналогично 4 байтовый и принимают схожие значения. Массив символов тоже был указан, однако всё так, как и было - `Invali record size` не исчез. Могу предположить, что должна быть иная реализация вызова packed record.

Comment: `char[] holder = new char[40];` - указатель на массив? В Дельфи данное поле не является указателем, тело массива непосредственно в структуре лежит. Сверяли sizeof для структуры со значением из Delphi?

Comment: В первом поле у вас char 16-битный должен быть, а вот в строковых массивах - восьмибитный (в прошлой теме вы говорили, что Delphi версия старая, с Char=AnsiChar, а не UnicodeChar)

Comment: По идее, если я всё правильно понимаю, что я могу заменить массивы char (16 битовый) на byte (8 битовый). Но после запуска ошибка осталась

Comment: В принципе, гоняться за байтами не зная нужного размера можно еще долго. Почему бы не убедиться сначала в том, какой размер подойдет, например сделав структуру из 1166 байт (если MBo прав, и в Делфе она такая)  и проверив что `myLib.GetAccountInfo` с ней стыкуется нормально. А потом уже будете подгонять типы.

Comment: 1166 байт - как я понимаю размерность только одного символьного типа. Без учёта остальных переменных. Как один из вариантов, есть возможность использовать уменьшенную packed record на 8 аргументов вместо 24. И на ней проверить догадку с выделением байтов.

Comment: Ну да. А то сейчас у вас 2 проблемы накладывается - работает ли вообще передача, и правильно ли размеры стыкуются. Делите на 2 задачи и решайте их по отдельности )

Comment: 1166 байт - sizeof всей структуры

Comment: Так, получилось следующее. Из структуры удалил все переменные, оставил только size и account(первые два из списка). Ошибки не выводит, но теперь выдаёт при попытки считывания поля account какие то не внятные цифры: `-130351100` не меняясь. Что это может быть? Закодированное число аккаунта?

Comment: Сейчас получилось достать кое какую информацию с помощью указания размерности 1166 байт. Но есть ещё проблема в том, что Array of char можно получить разметкой в байтах byte[] и только после этого получается вытащить инфу в странном виде, где `  я бонус                                  їњ  л` типо такого.

Comment: Видимо, для Ansi строки кодовую страницу нужно каким-то образом использовать (например, CP1251)

Comment: Всё бы вроде бы окей, но как раз её я и использую) Попробовал кодировки другие, но там кракозябры встречают пламенным приветом. 
Собственно думаю, что может это какая то особенность перевода из байтов в строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод packed record через JNA в Java производится следующим образом.
Вывод производится с помощью структуры.
В запакованной записи первый аргумент (Size, в конкретном случае) отвечает за размерность всей структуры, туда мы и передаём размер из delphi (sizeof всей структуры packed record).

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({"Size", "Account", "Card", "Holder", "Scheme", "Offered", "Expired", "Birthday", "Deleted","Locked", "Seize", "WhyLocked", "Discount", "Bonus", "PayLimit", "Female", "Folder", "Unpay", "Tel1", "Tel2", "Email", "Address", "DopInfo", "Balance"})
public class TAccountInfo extends Structure{
    //В конкретном случае 1166 байт
    public char Size = 1166;
    public int Account;
    public byte[] Card = new byte[32];
    public byte[] Holder = new byte[50];
    public byte Scheme;
    public int Offered;
    public int Expired;
    public int Birthday;
    public boolean Deleted;
    public boolean Locked;
    public boolean Seize;
    public byte[] WhyLocked = new byte[255];
    public char Discount;
    public char Bonus;
    public long PayLimit;
    public boolean Female;
    public short Folder;
    public int Unpay;
    public byte[] Tel1 = new byte[15];
    public byte[] Tel2 = new byte[15];
    public byte[] Email = new byte[255];
    public byte[] Address = new byte[255];
    public byte[] DopInfo = new byte[255];
    public long Balance;
}
```

Далее мы выполняем соответствия типов и инициализируем массивы. Ниже приведу использованные значения для маппинга.

```
+---------------------+---------------------------+
|       Delphi        |           Java            |
+---------------------+---------------------------+
| Word                | char или short            |
| Int64               | long                      |
| Array[0..n] of Char | byte[] name = new byte[n] |
| BOOL                | boolean                   |
| Comp                | long                      |
| Byte                | byte                      |
+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

Остальные типы приводятся в соответствии с размерностью байтов.

Огромная благодарность за помощь [MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo) и [Kromster](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177188/kromster)!